# How can I use multiprocessing for a function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn multiprocessing in python but it does not work in its very early steps.
for example in the code below:

```
counter = 2
def train_func():
    counter1 = counter*2

p1 = mp.Process(target=train_func)
p2 = mp.Process(target=train_func)

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print(counter1)
```

the result is that NameError: name 'counter1' is not defined. It seems that it does not enter the function. what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use some simple functions the easyest way is to use a Pool. Your code will look somethig like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

results = []
def saveres(res):
   results.append(res)

pool = Pool(nJobs)
print pool.map(f, range(10))

for i in range(10):
    pool.apply_async(f, (i,), callback=saveres)
```

Comment: this will not work as might be expected,  each process will have it's own distinct global `results` that is being appended to. `multiprocessing` does not share state, it is distinct python processes